# How to make shamrock image

Tags: python, matplotlib, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to make a shamrock crystal for later fabrication, and am using nazca design tool for doing it.

How can I place the trapezoid so that the sides of the trapezoid are parallel to the cyrcles and are always at the end of the sharp corners.

```
import nazca as nd
import numpy as np
# Define parameters
a = 500
semib = 0.255 * a
semia = semib * 0.75
shift = 0.22 * a
thickness = 0.65 * a
f = 2 * semia / np.sqrt(3)
r = semia

with nd.Cell(name="shamrock") as sham:
    # Create circles for the shamrock pattern
    circ1 = nd.geometries.circle(radius=semia, N=100)
    circ2 = nd.geometries.circle(radius=semia, N=100)
    circ3 = nd.geometries.circle(radius=semia, N=100)

    # Create Polygon objects for circles
    circ1_polygon = nd.Polygon(layer=56, points=circ1)
    circ2_polygon = nd.Polygon(layer=56, points=circ2)
    circ3_polygon = nd.Polygon(layer=56, points=circ3)

    # Place circles for the shamrock pattern using put
    circ1_polygon.put(0, shift)
    circ2_polygon.put(-shift * 0.5 * np.sqrt(3), -shift * 0.5)
    circ3_polygon.put(shift * 0.5 * np.sqrt(3), -shift * 0.5)

    # Identify sharp corners
    sharp_corner1 = ((-shift * 0.5 * np.sqrt(3)) / 2, (shift + (-shift * 0.5)) / 2)
    sharp_corner2 = ((0 + (shift * 0.5 * np.sqrt(3))) / 2, (shift + (-shift * 0.5)) / 2)
    sharp_corner3 = ((-shift * 0.5 * np.sqrt(3) + (shift * 0.5 * np.sqrt(3))) / 2, (-shift * 0.5 + (-shift * 0.5)) / 2)
    semicircle_radius  =  f-r
    # Create trapezoid using the trapezoid function
    
    trapezoid_shape = nd.geometries.trapezoid(length=50, height=160, angle1=132, angle2=132, position=1)

    # Create Polygon object for trapezoid
    trapezoid_polygon = nd.Polygon(layer=56, points=trapezoid_shape)

    # Place trapezoid at the sharp corners
    trapezoid_polygon.put(25,75,180)


nd.export_plt(sham)
```

And here is the picture.

[image]

[image]

Ideally would be nice to have something like this with the smoothen corners. But I was thinking to put a trapezoid on top to have smoothen the sharper corners.

Comment: you are using the nazca library but tagged matplotlib, which is not used in your code... which solution are you looking for?

Comment: I would like any solution as long as it gives me the result I am looking for, later I will implemet it in Nazca.

Comment: Are you looking for the formulae of trapezoid vertex coordinates? Is so, then this is a mathematical, not a programming problem.